# Bootstrap carousel caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implement carousel using below code. In this i want two caption as per carousel slide. So i will add one more caption div but it's not working properly.I need one caption for top left corner of the carousel another one bottom of the carousel. I am not aware of css so please help anyone.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
      <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Chicago</h3>
      <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. but you can give example in https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/21036h5c/8/

Comment: Thank u for reply.For example i want the text inside the<h3> tag is come on top left of the carousel and the text in <p> tag come on center on the carousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below sample will help you ,

Make the caption 100% width and height , and override  some properties for poth the h3 and p text (using media queries for different views)

```css
.carousel-caption {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0 !important;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:30px;
}
.carousel-caption p {
  margin-top:40%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-top:20%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 640px){
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-top:30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 641px) {
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-top:40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New York">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welocme :)

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help.

for example here > https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/21036h5c/10/

```
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3 class="text-right">Los Angeles</h3>
    <p  class="text-right">LA is always so much fun!</p>
  </div>
```

and css

```
.carousel-caption {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part was all i needed and helped.

```css
.carousel-caption {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0 !important;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:30px;
}
.carousel-caption p {
  margin-top:40%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-top:20%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 640px){
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-top:30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 641px) {
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-top:40%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30409164)